# What is the difference between these two implementation of singleton?

Tags: java, c#, singleton

I am having problem to understand the difference between these two function. Aren't they both implementing singleton? If so whats the benefit over one another.

```
    private static GameManager instance = new GameManager();
    public static GameManager get(){return instance;}
```

and the bellow,

```
    private static GameManager _instance;

    public static GameManager instance(){
     if(_instance == null) _instance = new GameManager();
     return _instance;
    }
```

Comment: The first one is instantiated in constructor. (new GameManager() goes to constructor). But they are both the same.

Comment: If you intend to use this singleton in a multithreaded context with locking and etc., then instantiation of that singleton should be done carefully. and that is why they use the second implementation with using locks,lazy(in C#), etc.

Comment: In Java, the second version does not guarantee a single instantiation of the field. If the class is accessible in a concurrent way, you should use a holder class to do it (or synchronize the method, which is more expensive and so to avoid)

Comment: Neither is optimal. Eager initialization is better (the first way) because it's simpler and Java lazily initializes classes anyway. The second way is complicated and unnecessary. Neither is correct; they don't guarantee singletonness. The right approach is to use an enum with a single enum constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main differences:

1. The first example is "eager", and the second one is "lazy".  Specifically, the first one will create the singleton object as soon as the singleton class is initialized, but the second one will create the singleton object when `instance()` is called the first time.

   Generally speaking, *eager* initialization is simpler.  However, it may be the case that initialization may depend on other things, and *lazy* initialization provides a way to defer the initialization until they have happened.
2. The second example has an insidious problem if two or more threads can call `instance()` simultaneously.  Specifically, the two threads *might* get different `GameManager` objects.

   The analogous problem in the first example is that one thread might see a `null` if there is an issue with class initialization cycles in the application.  That could lead to one thread seeing a `null` value.  However, the semantics of class initialization mean that there is a *happens-before* relation between class initialization and calling a method on the initialized class.  Therefore, both threads are guaranteed to see the correct initial state for the `GameManager` object.

---

But note that the "double checked lock" example is only correct for Java 5 and later.

---

If there are multiple threads sharing the `GameManager` instance, it is most likely necessary to do other things to get the application to (always) behave correctly.

Answer (score 3):

They are both implemented as singleton. The only difference is that the Singleton instance is Lazy Loaded on the second code block. In other words, it won't initialize the GameManager until `instance` method is called.

You should also probably rewrite your code to something simpler such as:

```
public static GameManager instance = new GameManager();
```

Comment: Incorrect implementation, in that the instance is not `final`, the class is not `final`, and the constructor is not `private`.

Comment: Smart ass. The question is tagged as C#/Java where there's no final keyword.

Comment: Please do be so kind as to excuse my failure to be explicit in establishing​ that I was speaking from the context of Java programming, for which atrocity I hope to atone by my acknowledgement thereof herein.

Comment: Acknowledged. :)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the second implementation is no good in multi-threaded environment because it may create more than one instance. This is when two  threads check if instance == null at the same time and both get true

Note that option #1 can also be lazy:

```
class GameManager {
    private static GameManager instance = new GameManager();

    private GameManager() {
        System.out.println("instance created");
    }

    public static GameManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Try to use it and you will see that instance is created only when we first call getInstance()

Comment: Neither implementation is correct as shown, which should be mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

The first implementation is more safely than other one implementation in multiple processor.Following rule guarantee why first implementation is safely.

Because the `JLS 17.4.5 Happens-before Order` define one rule:

**The default initialization of any object happens-before any other actions (other
than default-writes) of a program.**

so the `instance` field is initialized fully when someone call the method get().

The second implementation is called `lazy initialization`,but it is not correctly in your code.In order to staring program faster,using the `lazy initialization` is a good practice if the initialization of `GameManager` spend more time.

With second implementation,there is two approach which can make the `GameManager` thread safe.

The first,you can make the method `instance` synchronized,just like this:

```
public synchronized static GameManager instance(){
 if(_instance == null) _instance = new GameManager();
 return _instance;
}
```

But it is not high performance,because every call will be synchronized with that method in multiple thread.

The second,you can use `double-check` in the method `instance`,**and declare the `_instance` as `volatile`**,the following code:

```
static volatile GameManager _instance;

public static GameManager instance(){
    if (_instance== null) {              //0
        synchronized(GameManager.class) {  //1
            if (_instance == null)          //2
                _instance= new GameManager ();  //3
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

This implementation code is correctly and high performance.

Why the `field`_instance`should be volatile?Let's see the following situation with no`volatile`,there is two thread called`thread1`and`thread2`,and they all call the method`instance()`:

1. thread1 run at point 0 in above code
2. thread1 check the `_instance` is null and no one acquire the lock,so it can run at point 3
3. with the code `_instance= new GameManager ();  //3` ,because of the instruction reorder in `Java Memory Model`,the `JVM` can break up the instruction order in 'interpreter`or`jit`.Let's see what happened with that code.The instance has been constructed,the constructing instance is just be allocated memory(like the instruction`new`in`JVM`,not in`JAVA`),and then assign to the field`_instance`,but notice the instance is not initialize completely(for example,not initialize field with default value,or call static construct method);
4. The thread2 run at point 0,and check the `_instance` is not null,so it will return the `_instance` which is not initialize fully,and the instance is not 
   trustworthy.

If the `_instance` is `volatile`,the `volatile` can guarantee the `_instance` initialize fully when someone read it.See the `17.4.5 Happens-before Order`,there is one rule:

**A write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of
that field.t**

Comment: Incorrect implementation, in that the instance is not `final`, the class is not `final`, and the constructor is not `private`. The description of `volatile` is incomplete; other writes and reads have _happens-before_ established by actions through a `volatile` variable. Lacks explanation why lazy initialization is not wise or needed. Lacks mention of the preferred enum approach.